# $watch for objects in JSON Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, watch

I want to create a $watch in a directive to a specific part of a json object but it doesn't seem to accept the syntax (no errors appear, but it never goes inside the watch)

```
link: function (scope, element) {
scope.JsonObject={
    profs:{
        prof1:[{
           name:example1a,
           id:example1b
        }],
        prof2:[{
           name:example2a,
           id:example2b
        }]
     }
 }  

scope.teachers=scope.JsonObject['profs']

//until here all ok

for ( var  teacher in scope.teachers){
    //stuff to do
    console.log("creating watch of " + teacher);

    scope.$watch('teachers[teacher]', function() {  //here seems to be the problem (it doesnt seem to accept JsonObject.teacher)       
    //stuff to do

}, true);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by creating a watch inside the directive, please make it clear and also a plunkr with your code will be helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: what I do is call a highcharts plugin :
 new Highcharts.chart(teacher + "_id",chartoptions); 

but in this case I dont think it's relevant, the problem is that it never goes inside the watch anyway

Comment: `JsonObject.teacher` is `undefined` so you can use `JsonObject.profs` or `teacher.profs`

Comment: Yep, sorry I messed up a little while passing my code to the question format. Thank you for noticing, already edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, `teachers[teacher]` was `undefined` because there were no `' '`(quotes)
around the `teacher`.

```
for (var teacher in $scope.teachers){
    $scope.$watch("teachers['"+ teacher +"']", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      alert("changed");
   }, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what I was looking for.
However in case anyone is new in this (like me) and has the same problem it is important to know that:

1) It is not possible to acces the variable "teacher" inside the watch since the value might have changed for the time of the execution of the watch, use newValue , oldValue instead

2) Don't create debugger's or breakpoints inside the watch since it will pop up an error: main execution waits for the never ending termination of the watch (I think). Instead use traces for debugging like console.log()

Answer (score 1):

The string doesnt get interolated into the object.

```
function getTeacher(teacher) {
   return $scope.teachers[teacher]
}

scope.$watch(getTeacher(teacher), function() {
//Do stuff
},  true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use use an outside value inside a $watch, specially inside a loop. Picture it as an interval, if you put an interval or a timeout inside a loop, the value of the variable handled outside the interval ('$scope.teachers[teacher]' in this case) will not be accesible from the inside, or at least will take the last iteration value.

Comment: True, I commented something similar on a previous answer, but this is also what happened.